MacOS: setAppBadge() not called by service worker if pwa/ installed web app is closed
Hi everyone I really need some help. I've looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer.
I have a PWA with push notifications and badging.

the PWA works fine in iOS: it receives notifications AND setAppBadge works fine even if the app is closed (i.e. the badge is correctly set)
on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 with the PWA/ web app  installed to dock via Safari 17.4.1: everything works fine it the app is open; if the app is closed however I still get the push notification alert but setAppBadge doesn't seem to work (i.e. the badge is not set)

Here's the "test" code from the service worker:
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    let promises = [];

    if ('setAppBadge' in self.navigator) {
        const badgeCount = 1; //fake data
        const promise = self.navigator.setAppBadge(badgeCount);
        promises.push(promise);
    }
    promises.push(self.registration.showNotification("You've got mail!"));
    event.waitUntil(Promise.all(promises));
});

The code is straight out from https://webkit.org/blog/14112/badging-for-home-screen-web-apps/
I tried other combinations/ permutations (number-string arg, show notification before-after setappbadge, ...). It always works fine on iOS, not on macOS
To summarize: setAppBadge works as expected with the PWA/ webapp closed on an iPhone, not on a Mac
Thanks in advance

I can confirm this problem for Safari 17.5 (osx), but also have no solution. Apple unfortunately doesn't support PWAs well.
